# How to prevent matplotlib from showing decimal years in horizontal axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
t = [2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017]
s = [12.92, 14.19, 15.39, 15.72, 16.03]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s, 'o', markersize=15)
ax.set(xlabel='year', ylabel='Revenue (billion dollars)',
       title='Revenue Growth')
fig.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

The output is here, but the horizontal axis represents year; how can I stop it from showing decimal years?

[image]

Comment: Easiest in the case of having all successive years could be to make them categories. `t = np.array(t).astype(str)`. Else you can set the ticks and labels via `ax.set_xticks(t); ax.set_xticklabels(t)`. In general, the solution would be to use a locator (e.g. a `MultipleLocator(1)` and formatter, (e.g. `StrMethodFormatter`). Finally, you can convert your `t` to `datetimes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a possible solution is converting your array to numpy array and passing it as string:

```
ax.plot(np.asarray(t).astype(str), s, 'o', markersize=15)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
```

Comment: In this case you will also need a locator. (I listed all options in my comment below the question.)